# Using the system Terminal when running C# Console applications in Visual Studio for Mac 8.6.2

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

A few days ago I updated my Visual Studio for Mac to the 8.6.2 version and I noticed one of the new features which is the new integrated Terminal. But I don't like it - it is buggy and it's  generally not doing what I need it to. So, I tried searching for a solution on the internet, but never found one. The next thing that I tried was to downgrade to the latest version of Visual Studio for Mac 2017, but when I start the installation, it stays on Preparing installation 0% for hours. I want to go back to the old system terminal. When I run my app, I want it to start in a new instance of the system terminal, just like before. Is there a way to make that happen?

I want to point out that I'm in university and I'm using Visual Studio only for C# Console applications - for now.

I will be more than grateful if someone helps me with fixing that issue. Thank you all in advance! Hope you have a great day. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch back to the old behaviour of using the external macOS Terminal.app by:

1. From the main menu select **Preferences** to open the Preferences dialog
2. Select **Other** - **Terminal**
3. Uncheck **Enable integrated terminal**
4. Click the **OK** button to save the changes.

[image]

Also it would be helpful if you could report problems you are having with the integrated Terminal on the [Visual Studio for Mac Developer Community page](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/41/index.html).

Comment: Thank you a lot! That helped me and fixed my problem. Thank you! :)